# Does Google Actions support adjust light brightness or color temperature in relative manner?

Tags: google-smart-home

We reviewed the google smart home protocol about light brightness (https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/brightness) and color temperature. Looks like it still lacks support adjusting them in relative manner. Only the absolute value is supported. Is it true? Will it be supported soon?

We also tested on Google Home app, the google platform will send a absolute value to us though we asked it to "adjust the light brighter."

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like it still lacks support adjusting them in relative manner. Only the absolute value is supported.

This is true in the sense that there is no explicit command like `BrightnessRelative` for your integration to handle. The platform supports relative commands from users through the Assistant grammar, which determines the new state for the trait (such as `Brightness`) based on its current state value.